Incoherent face index result of ray_cast
I do a ray_cast from the camera along its direction to get the hit face:
def find_hit_face(camera, direction):
    _, _, _, hit_face_index, hit_object, _ = (
        scene.ray_cast(
            depsgraph=context.view_layer.depsgraph,
            origin=camera.location,
            direction=direction,
            distance=camera.data.clip_end,
        )
    )
    polygons = hit_object.data.polygons()
    return polygons[hit_face_index]

But I got the error IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 5544 out of range, size 2224.
How can I get the hit face from the hit face index?

Hello ! I think you need to use the evaluated object. I assume the object has generative modifiers that modify it's number of polygons ?

Thank you for the suggestion. This is exactly the problem.
I've used updated_object = hit_object.evaluated_get(context.view_layer.depsgraph) instead of hit_object and it works.

You need to query the evaluated object. By default raycasting acts on the evaluated scene so you want to query the evaluated object's polygons.
import bpy

def find_hit_face(camera, direction):
    _, _, _, hit_face_index, hit_object, _ = (
        scene.ray_cast(
            depsgraph=context.view_layer.depsgraph,
            origin=camera.location,
            direction=direction,
            distance=camera.data.clip_end,
        )
    )
    polygons = hit_object.evaluated_get(bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph).data.polygons
    return polygons[hit_face_index]

Link to bpy.types.ID.evaluated_get docs
